# How do I search if a particular string is present in a df column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of movies which contains a number of genres - e.g. Column 1 and a number of keywords relating to the plot - e.g. Column 2. What I want to do is get a new dataframe with just entries related to a particular genre, e.g. 'Sci-fi'. The issue I have is that some entries are multi-genre e.g. 'Horror, Sci-fi, Thriller'.

Here is what I have tried:

```
df[(df == 'Sci-fi').any(axis=1)]
```

This only gives me entries where there is one type of genre in Column 1. It does not give me any entries which contain 'Sci-fi' and another genre. How can I get my df to show multi-genre entries containing the genre 'Sci-fi'?

Comment: `df['Column1'].str.split(',\s+').explode().eq('Sci-fi').any(level=0)`.

Comment: `df["Column1"].str.contains("Sci-fi")`

Comment: That's great, I'm pretty sure all solutions would work, but @not_speshal 's solution was the first I tried which gave me what I needed. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ['Horror, Sci-fi, Thriller', 'Horror, Thriller', 'Sci-fi'], 'Column2': [1, 2, 3]})
print(df[df['Column1'].str.extract('(Sci-fi)', expand=False).notna()])
```

Output:

```
                    Column1  Column2
0  Horror, Sci-fi, Thriller        1
2                    Sci-fi        3
```